# Array Cap overwritten

Tags: go

GO MASTERs! could you advise?

1. with make([]int,len,cap), does GO allow array initialization at the same time to declaration?

   `myArray := make([]int, 3, 10){1,2,3}`
2. I see cap(myArray) has changed as same to len(myArray) in the below case. What is fundamental behind?

`<ex>
       myArray := make([]int, 3, 10)
       myArray = []int{1,2,3}
       fmt.Println("len:"len(myArray),", cap:",cap(myArray))`

> len:3, cap:3

Why cap(myArray) is 3 instead of 10 as I declaration?

I initialized individual element directly. And, it works as I wanted

`<ex>
       myArray := make([]int, 3, 10)
       myArray[0] = 1
       myArray[1] = 2
       myArray[2] = 3
       fmt.Println("len:"len(myArray),", cap:",cap(myArray))`

> len:3, cap:10

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're getting this result because in the first example you declare a slice with a length of 3 and a cap of 10. However, in the following statement you assign a completely different slice to that variable. Since the slice your assigning was declared/initialized using 'composite-literal' syntax and it has only 3 items, that is the capacity it is initialized with. In your second example, you assign values to each index of the slice you created with make, retaining the length and capacity properties.

To try and give more clarification... In C# or Java or C++ this would be like doing something like this;

```
List<string> myStrings = new List<string>();
myStrings.Add("A string");

myStrings = new List<string>();
```

As you might assume, after assigning a new list to the myStrings variable the old list is lost. So to give the simple answer, you're not just overwriting the cap, you're overwriting the whole slice. The value you have in your assignment that overwrites it, causes a slice to be created with a cap of 3 which is why you get that result.

Comment: I'd say you declare just a slice of int and allocate an instance with length of 3 and a cap of 10. You can declare and instantiate in one expression due short declaration form.

Comment: Thanks Uvelichitel but, it is not clear if you meant I can do instantiate even with make? 2nd way which []int{***} can achieve it but if 'make()' can do or not is my question.

Comment: Yeah I'm not not sure what @Uvelichitel is trying to convey. The `make` statement allocates a slice of length 3, capacity 10. The `x := []int{1,2,3}` is called 'composite literal' instantiation and much like with makes mechanics, since there is no capacity specified (no where to put that info) the capacity defaults to the length (this works the same when you call make omitting the third argument).

Comment: I'm trying to convey that there is type just 'slice of int' []int which variable can have. And you can assign slice with any cap and len to that variable. Otherwise I'm agree with @evanmcdonnal answer, I vote it up.

Answer (score 2):

So there's a few things at play here. I would strongly recommend the goblog's explanation of this: https://blog.golang.org/slices (go down to the section labeled Capacity). Also, just a (tiny) bit of semantics, but those are actually slices, not arrays :)

To get to the point, when you first declared your slice, you had a len of 3 and a capacity of 10. No problem with that. But then you redeclare myArray, and set it to be []int{1,2,3}. No problems there either, this is valid.

The problem comes when you expected your previous len/cap to remain the same; your slice is just a pointer to some space in memory. So you've now changed your underlying pointer (see the goblog). The capacity and length of the slice is now changed as well (to the default-- again, see the goblog). You can see the same changing of len/cap if you were to add more elements:

```
myArray := make([]int, 3, 10)
fmt.Println("len:"len(myArray),", cap:",cap(myArray)) // len: 3 cap: 10

myArray := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println("len:", len(myArray), "cap:", cap(myArray)) // len: 3 cap: 3

myArray = append(myArray, 4)
fmt.Println("len:", len(myArray), "cap:", cap(myArray)) // len: 4 cap: 8; automatically increases the cap
```

Comment: Thanks william for good comment and blog! So, it seems I generated two slices (with len, cap) and myArray has redirected to the later one while I was expecting the first one retained. And, the built-function (Append) will do either reslice if mothership (array) has enough memory allocated or, regenerate array & slice if the original slice is over the capacity. Please advise more if I missed points ;)

Comment: BTW, is only way to create ARRAY (not slice) is 'var array []int ' ?